# How to make different aspect ration images into same width and height without getting cropped?

Tags: javascript, css, image, aspect-ratio

I have multiple `div` with class called `card`. I need my all `div` to be same height and same width. I want to add images to those `div`. I have different images with different aspect ratios. Also I want whole image filled inside the div. (I want to prevent from cropped images). Therefore, If I can convert all images into same aspect ratio first, then it should be okay. Then I can set `.card-img {width=100%}`. Height should be same for all images because `.card` has same width and all images have same aspect ratio. How can I make this work as I mentioned?

```
<div class="card">
 <img class="card-img" src="img-1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="card">
 <img class="card-img" src="img-2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="card">
 <img class="card-img" src="img-3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

---

```
.card{
 width: 270px
 height: 400px;
}
```

Assume img-1.jpg, img-2.jpg, img-3.jpg has different aspect ratios.

Comment: You can use the images in the background and define them to be `background-size: cover;`. 
Have a look at the possible values of the `background-size` rule and see if any of them will help you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: @Adriano The Problem when I make it to `background-size: cover` is it crops some of the images because all images are not in same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force an image to have a different aspect ratio from its natural one without either cropping or distorting it. You say you don't want to crop so that is not a possibility and you would be unlikely to want to distort it (stretch it in one direction or the other).

What you can do is make sure that the whole image is always visible is use `contain` instead of `cover`.

Obviously this means there will be space either at the top and bottom or at the sides of your cards in some cases but this is an inevitable consequence of the no-cropping requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem many a times. Unfortunately the only options we have available when height and width are fixed are:

1. Use `object-fit: cover` on the img element. This results in some cropping.
2. Use `object-fit: contain` on the img element. This ensures there is no cropping but adds whitespace around the image.

If you are okay with differing height and width, then you have the option to use a masonry layout as described here:
https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Answer (score -1):

Easy, just set max width and max height to 100% and let the browser sort it out.

```css
.card {
 width: 270px;
 height: 400px;
 border: 1px solid #333;
}
.card img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
 <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/370/400" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="card">
 <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/400/100" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="card">
 <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="" />
</div>
```

This is in case you want the image element. If you want the image as a background, use the `contain` property.

**UPDATE**

If you want the images to fill the cells, use

```
.card img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

But this will stretch the image. These are the two options you have without cropping.